# System or critical user never log in

Tags: active-directory

Besides Exchange, does AD itself, or other well known apps create user objects but never use it for login? I am trying to clean up inactive accounts and don't want to remove something that appears unused but actually important. Specifically, is it safe to remove any account whose lastlogonstamp is NULL (so it's never logged in) but was created long time ago (again, excluding Exchange objects)?

Comment: `is  it safe to remove any account whose lastlogonstamp is NULL`. No it is not. There will always be exceptions. We aren't going to know what those exceptions are for your environment, you should review the accounts and see what makes sense for exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

It is not safe to remove or even block accounts which has `LastLogonTimeStamp` set to NULL or every old date. Some LDAP authentication scenarios do not update this attribute in AD, although systems might be actively using an account.

Also, please see answer to https://serverfault.com/a/1079561/321227

Comment: Accepted as answer, though I am not convinced how an account is actively being used when lastLogonTimeStamp is not populated except a few well known setups. Also I'd belive bugs you mentioned have long been fixed.